# Lower bound on $x^T A x$ when A is non-symmetric with positive eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, quadratic-forms

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$ be a $m \times 1$ vector and $A \in \mathbb{R}$ be a non-symmetric $m \times m$ matrix with real and positive eigenvalues.

Is there a lower bound on $x^T A x$ of the form $\kappa ||x||^2$ with $\kappa >0$ ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is no. Consider the example

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\-4&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}=-2<0.$$

Comment: @mlf:What condition should be imposed no $A$ so that there is always a lower bound on $x^TAx$ of the form $\kappa ||x||^2$?

Comment: @PKStyles We need the matrix to be symmetric. In such a case it is diagonalizable. So there exists $P$ such that $P^{-1}AP= \rm{diag} (\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n)$ and $(x_1,\dots,x_n)^T \rm{diag}(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n)(x_1,\dots,x_n)=\sum_i\lambda_ix_i^2>0$ if $(x_1,\dots,x_n)\ne 0.$